# Calling a webservice from js in a web application

Tags: javascript, wcf, web-services, web-applications, scriptmanager

I have created a simple webmethod which is used to keep a session alive:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web

<ServiceContract(Namespace:="PMWebService")>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class WebService

' To use HTTP GET, add <WebGet()> attribute. (Default ResponseFormat is WebMessageFormat.Json)
' To create an operation that returns XML,
'     add <WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml)>,
'     and include the following line in the operation body:
'         WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "text/xml"
<OperationContract()>
Public Shared Function KeepSessionAlive() As Integer

    'Keep the session alive by writing to a session variable
    HttpContext.Current.Session("KeepSessionAlive") = DateTime.Now
    'Give the user time to keep the session alive
    Dim iSecondsToKeepAlive As Integer = 50
    'Set the timeout before the 'keep alive' message is displayed
    Dim iTimeout As Integer = (HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout * 60000) - (iSecondsToKeepAlive * 1000)
    Return iTimeout

End Function

' Add more operations here and mark them with <OperationContract()>

End Class
```

My scriptmanager is defined as follows:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMaster" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Shared/WebService.svc" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

I would like to be able to access this from all my webpages. I have tried creating a wcf service to call this by:

```
    $('.renew-session').click(function () {
        clearTimeout(modalTimeout);
        var stayAlive = new PMWebService.WebService
        stayAlive.KeepSessionAlive(onTimeoutReturned, onDataFailure);
    });
```

However this fails at "var stayAlive = new MyWebService.WebService" saying that PMWebService is undefined.

I have tried to follow the example at: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=235. However when I go through these steps I get a difference at Step 4. When I look at the properties for my scriptmanager I don't see a services collection. My website is running as a web application so I don't know if this would make any difference.

I hope someone can help with this. I have also tried running this as an asmx service but that gave the same error. I can run it as a PageMethod but I would have to put this on each page. I have also tried an ashx handler but don't think I can return a timeout value from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just sorted this out. I had to remove the 'Shared' from the definition of 'KeepSessionAlive'. I'd copied the routine from elsewhere and hadn't noticed the definition was incorrect.